# How to install a component from .pas file in delphi?

Tags: delphi, installation, package, delphi-2010, custom-component

i've downloaded the RealTimeMarquee component for embarcadereo delphi 2010 which comes as a two files

RealTimeMarquee.pas
SimpleHTML.pas

But when i tried to open the file using delphi to compile it, i can't see the green button ( compile / build ) activated.

My question: How to install this component.

thankyou

Comment: @menjaraz - I don't think this question applies only to a specific Delphi version.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: You are quite right. Retag done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question: How to install this component.

To install follow the steps below (same steps as [Remy Lebeau-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685593/1051198) )

Step #1 .
make a new package -

[image]

Step #2 . Select New package

[image]

Step #3 .

Add the source files RealTimeMarquee.pas,SimpleHTML.pas 
[image]

Step #4 .
[image]

Step #5 .
A)`Compile` and then `install`

[image]

Step #6 .
On successful installation you will get this message.
[image]

Step #7 .
You can save the `.dpk` file also
[image]

Step #8 .
Use the component from Tool Palatte

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You cannot compile the files by themselves.  You have to add them to a project first.  If you want to install them into the IDE's component palette (assuming one or both of them implements a `Register()` function), you have to create a new "Package" project, add the files to that project, then you can Compile the project and Install the package.