# Install x-superobject (.pas file) on delphi xe6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I want to use x-superobject, but I can't figure out how to add it and use it on delphi xe6. I found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685060/how-to-install-a-component-from-pas-file-in-delphi) on how to install .pas files on delphi, but it is for delphi2010 and thing are a little bit different I think (I've tried that one but it didn't worked.)

So, to install xsuperobject I downloaded [this two files](https://code.google.com/p/x-superobject/source/browse/#svn/trunk) and saved them. I don't know how to proceed, and I feel a bit stupid but I don't understand what is [here on the wiki.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Install_Component)

Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing to install in that repository. All you should do is put those files in some public folder (usually `C:\Users\Public\Documents\<Component Folder>`) and add that directory to the [`Library path`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Library). Then you can add any of those units in the `uses` clause of your project unit and the compiler should find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X-SuperObject` is a runtime library, not a visual component library. The installation is quite easy.

**Way 1:** Simply put the two files to your project source folder and then you are able to use them without any problems.

**Way 2:** If you hate to include the files to any of your projects, you can open the **Option** dialog and  goto `Environment Options` > `Delphi Options` > `Library`. You add the path of `X-SuperObject` to the `Browsing Path`.

Now you are able to include `XSuperObject` as any other Delphi native units (i.e. `Winapi.Windows`, `System.SysUtils`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Way 2 is absolutely perfect!